# Using jquery in popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add some elements in a popover and associate some commands with the elements.

Lets say I have following block:

```
<div id ="pop_models">
<a href="javascript:;" class="model">TEST MODEL</a>
</div>
```

And

```
    $(".model").click(function() {
        alert('I work');
    });
```

If I click on the link of course I will get an alert message.

However if I display my `div` using a popover the alert is not displayed, nothing happens when I click it.

I.e. I associate the following code with my popover

```
        $('[rel=popover]').popover({ 
            html : true, 
            content: function() {
              return $('#pop_models').html();
            }
        });
```

It seems that `$(".model").click(function() {` does not find `model` class in the popover.

Answer (score 0):

For the popover functionality ...this might help you

**HTML**

```
   <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true"
      data-content="<p>Example 1" title="Popover Method 1">Popover Method 1 1</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){ 
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
});
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, what I want is not the link to display the popover. But the #pop_models to be displayed in the popover such that when I click on the link .click(function) would work.

Answer (score 0):

When you bind a handler to an element like $('.model'), the handler is immediately tied to the lifecycle of that element.

Your content function is returning new HTML every time, so you're going to get a new DOM element created every time with no handlers.

You can address this by either:

1. Make sure you add your click handler to your element every time it is created or
2. Register your event on some [delegate](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) - a stable element which always exists in the DOM. The most basic (and not recommended) example being $(body).find('.model').click(function() {...});

#2 is hard because in theory you don't know where Bootstrap is actually going to insert the popover element into the DOM. So you'll have a hard time finding a good parent element to use as the delegate.

So you'll probably want to go with #1. You can do this by registering for [events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-events) from Bootstrap that will tell you when your element is in the DOM. Just add the code to register your click handler inside your event handler (either shown.bs.popover or inserted.bs.popover) and you'll be all set.